# Exact string match in multi line string

Tags: awk

I have a string as below, I needed to exactly match if string `"abc.properties abc Scanner directory: /xyz/xzy/"` is present.

I am using the below awk command.

It considers as successful if even a part of string, say, `abc.properties` is present. But, my criteria is to check for the exact string i.e. `"abc.properties abc Scanner directory: /xyz/xzy/"`.

Can somebody please help?

```
echo $s | awk 'BEGIN { FS="\n"; RS="";} /abc.properties abc Scanner directory: \/xyz/xzy\// {print $1}'
```

String is as below:

```
spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no -o ServerAliveInterval=600 -o ServerAliveCountMax=3 -o ConnectTimeout=30 xyz@123.abc.com Password: Creating directory '/home/xyz'. Authorized uses only. All activity may be monitored and reported. Successful login using -u option. If you want to allow X traffic please use -x option. Usage: /111/11/111/111 [policy] -x [target user] su from xyz to abc [abc@xyz ~]$ /111/111/111/111/111/111.sh /111/11/instance/111/111/111/111/ Verifying JVM setting for domain: /111/11/11/11/1111/111/111// abc.properties abc Scanner directory: /xyz/xzy/ [abc@xyz ~]$ exit 0 logout
```

The output is as below:

```
$ echo $s | awk 'BEGIN { FS="\n"; RS="";} /abc.properties abc Scanner directory:   \/xyz/xzy\// {print $1}'

spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no -o ServerAliveInterval=600 -o ServerAliveCountMax=3 -o ConnectTimeout=30 xyz@123.abc.com Password: Creating directory '/home/xyz'. Authorized uses only. All activity may be monitored and reported. Successful login using -u option. If you want to allow X traffic please use -x option. Usage: /111/11/111/111 [policy] -x [target user] su from xyz to abc [abc@xyz ~]$ /111/111/111/111/111/111.sh /111/11/instance/111/111/111/111/ Verifying JVM setting for domain: /111/11/11/11/1111/111/111// abc.properties abc Scanner directory: /xyz/xzy/ [abc@xyz ~]$ exit 0 logout
```

Comment: please format the last code.

Comment: Sorry, Now it seems to have got formatted.

Comment: what's the output of your command? You fail to escape forward slash in this `\/xyz/xzy\//` regex.

Comment: My expectation is the awk command should be successful only when full matching string is provided i.e. "abc.properties abc Scanner directory: \/xyz/xzy\/" and not even when part of the matching string eg. "abc.properties" is provided.

Currently it is successful even with part of the string like "abc.properties"

Comment: post your actual input? you set the FS as "\n" but there isn't a new line in your input string.

Comment: Yeah Avinash, I have made a mistake to use "\n" for FS where the string does not contain the \n.

I have provided the actual command used in the Question

Comment: But your actual command shows `FS="\n"`.

Comment: IS the string on a single line ?